# Location.state is undefined on first time visiting a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-history

I am passing state through history.push() on onClick event like so

```
<Component
   onClick={
      history.push({
        pathname: path,
        search: query,
        state: { from: location.pathname }
      })
   }
/>
```

and I am accessing the state in a hook with state as dependency.

```
const prev_state = useRef()
const location = useLocation()

useEffect(() => {
   if(location.state) {
      prev_state.current = location.state
   }
}, [location.state])
```

the issue is that the state is always undefined the first time I visit the component. I can access the state on any further visits to the same component (which means I go back and come back again) until I refresh the page. Why can't I access state on the first visit?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "first time visiting component".

If you rendered a button and click it to go to the second component, and the second component's state is always undefined at first visit, then it's because you used didmount.

DidMount is called before render. And first render will always render undefined.

If not, I suggest you to describe your situation in details as your description is somewhat confusing.

Comment: About the did mount hook I have also tried giving location.state as dependency to the hook and have update the code in my question. I am not talking about the first render I am talking about the first time I visit a screen with that component. When I go back and come back again to the same component It re mounts the component again but this time I get the state from the location.

Comment: You pass state using history.push() function. When you visit first time by routing, in that case no state information is given and it is just undefined. Maybe just giving default value for this case should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's in your props. You could access your history state object like this:

```
this.props.location.state
```

Comment: I am using functional component with useLocation hook. I have updated my question above.